# How to refresh a View in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I use Two view's on same ViewController and use two animation 1. Flip Back Animation 2. Background Horizontal image animation (image view is sliding from right to left on view1).Now, when i flip from view1 to view2 everything is correct But when i flip back from view2 to view1 than (slide image view animation stop to slide and become static on view1). I need to refresh the view1 as it work properly . I used these two suggested method by Ved
  View1.setNeedsDisplay()
  View1.setNeedsLayout()
But it's also not work . Please share info

[image]

Comment: sorry sahil there is nothing important to share i just calling a method two times . Actually i used flip back animation when i return form second view to first view than all the data of first view become static , i use an horizontal animation image view which stop on flip back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write all the code in      viewWillappear() . This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Must put func in **viewWillAppear**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    func run() { //Here Code Run }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a view to refresh by calling

```
yourView.setNeedsDisplay() //Updates any drawing, including drawRect()
```

and

```
yourView.setNeedsLayout() //Triggers layoutSubviews()
```

Comment: Ved Thanks for Your Comment But its not working The view remain static , its not moving